# ORACLE: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone tell me what's wrong in my code. I need to create function that displays the number of digits given a number but I keep getting missing in and out parameter. Im am using Oracle SQL. Thank you

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
        
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  Digit (n1 IN OUT INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER IS
    Counter INTEGER  := 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE (n1 != 0 ) LOOP
        n1    := n1 /10;
        Counter := Counter + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN Counter;
END;
```

Test block:

```
DECLARE
    n1 INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN:
    n1 := &n1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The number of digit = ' ||Digit(Counter));  
END;
```

Comment: `counter` is not defined in the block.  `n1` is.

Comment: See the working example here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da0a780757a86ab30b326d0bcdbbb5d1

Comment: Removed "MYSQL" from the question title, because this appears to be about Oracle

Comment: You have a stray `:` at the end of `begin`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably because of the stray `:` character after `begin` in your test block.

I would write it like this:

```
create or replace function digits
    ( p_num integer )
    return integer
as
    pragma udf;
    i simple_integer := p_num;
    l_digits simple_integer := 0;
begin
    while i <> 0 loop
        i := i / 10;
        l_digits := l_digits + 1;
    end loop;

    return l_digits;
end digits;
```

I made the parameter `in` only, instead of `in out`. This means you can use it in SQL queries, and also in PL/SQL code without needing to pass in a variable whose value will get changed to 0 by the function.

`pragma pdf` tells the compiler to optimise the function for use in SQL.

I used `simple_integer` as in theory it's slightly more efficient for arithmetic operations, although I doubt any improvement is measurable in the real world (and I'm rather trusting the optimising compiler to cast my literal `10` as a simple_integer, as otherwise the overhead of type conversion will defeat any arithmetic efficiency).